# iframe's scroll: background doesn't rendered

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have to show an exterior page in the `iframe`. The `iframe's` width is relatively small (about 400px) and cannot be changed. The problem is that when I scroll the `iframe` horizontally I can see the background of the contained page is not drawn. But some pages are rendered normally.

The code to reproduce is very simple:

```html
<iframe src="http://ubuntu.com"></iframe>  
<iframe src="http://britannica.com"></iframe>  
<iframe src="http://linktiger.com"></iframe>  
<iframe src="http://youtown.com"></iframe>  
<iframe src="http://pagefreezer.com"></iframe>  <!-- ok -->  
<iframe src="http://imdb.com"></iframe>    <!-- ok -->
```

A picture is worth a thousand words: http://jsfiddle.net/rKfNA/3/

The background of these pages is specified using the ordinary `background` css property.

I've reproduced this in the all major browsers under ubuntu, android and windows.

Why the `iframe` is not showing them right? Is this a rendering engines' bug? Or is this 'by design'?
And what can I do to show content in the iframes right?
Could you help please?

Answer (score 1):

The background is set on the body. The body is the height en width of the iframe.

It is a bug made by the developers of the site. You can put an `iframe` in a `div`. The iframe **exactly** needs to be the width and height of the site you are showing. *There is no other way.*

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rKfNA/4/ (the widths and heights of the iframes are not the width and height of the site inside it, so there are double scrollbars)

Comment: Thank you! But my situation is so bad that the user desides which site she wants to see in the `iframe` and I don't know the size of the site and I can't obtain it with js because of the cross-domain restrictions. So it seems like there is no way at all. Can you suggest where to see for the prooflink?